# Ambiguous column name 'CustomerId'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following code -

```
declare @userType int
declare @custIdOfUser int

select 
    @userType = UserTypeId, @custIdOfUser = CustomerId 
from 
    customers c with (nolock)
left outer join 
    Sites s with (nolock) on c.CustomerId = s.CustomerId 
left outer join 
    customers rc on rc.CustomerId = c.ResellerId 
where 
    c.[name] is not null 
    and (c.customerId is null or rc.CustomerId = c.CustomerId) 
    and c.IsActive != ''
    and (@userType = 1 OR @userType = 2 OR 
           (c.customerId in ((SELECT u.CustomerId, ur.RoleId 
                              FROM Users u
                              INNER JOIN UserRoles ur ON ur.UserId = u.UserId AND ur.RoleId = 39
                              INNER JOIN Customers c ON ur.CustomerId = c.CustomerID 
                              WHERE u.UserId = 28 or u.UserTypeId = 3 or u.UserTypeId = 4 
                                and c.customerId in 
                                    (SELECT c.CustomerId FROM Customers c 
                                     WHERE c.resellerId = u.CustomerId )))))
```

It is giving me following error messages -

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'UserTypeId'.
>   Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Ambiguous column name 'CustomerId'.

Comment: can you format your query, please?  when you edit your post, there's a toolbar above the big text area... use the `{}` button and use spaces for logical indentation and line breaks so it is easy to read/understand...

Comment: You have `c.CustomerId IN ....` but then you select a set of data with **two columns** - that won't ever work! If you want to check `c.customerId`, then the sub-query must return a set of `customerId` values (and **only** those values - not additional columns!)

Comment: I think you left out at least one join against the customers table - seriously, do you need to join against customers FOUR TIMES?

Answer (score 2):

1. > Ambiguous column name 'CustomerId'

   You're getting this because you're selecting `CustomerId` without specifying which table to take it from. This column name exists on 3 of your tables (`UserRoles`, `Sites`and `Customers`), one of which you're joining to twice (`Customers c` and `Customers rc`). You should make your select statement more explicit e.g.

   ```
   select 
     @custIdOfUser = c.CustomerId
   ```
2. > Invalid column name 'UserTypeId'

   This column doesn't exist on any of your tables.
3. > Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

   – because you have this:

   ```
   c.customerId in ((SELECT u.CustomerId, ur.RoleId
   ```

   which should be this:

   ```
   c.customerId in ((SELECT u.CustomerId
   ```

Comment: I first wanted only to fix the `which should be this` paragraph, but then decided to throw in more, what seemed to me, "improvements". If they aren't so to you, please feel free to change/roll back them as you see fit.